# How to update state of the component with data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a problem with React and useState.

I'm trying to download all [characters from Star Wars API](https://swapi.dev/documentation#people). I'm using the Axios for this, so this code is just for importing Axios instance:

```
import { instance } from 'api/getCharacters';
```

You can see in the ***code sample*** that I have a button that runs the **getCharacters** async function which downloads 10 characters at the first call and 5 characters at all next calls (except the last call). I'm saving all the character's JSON to the **charactersArray**. You can also see that I'm passing my state variable which stores those characters to the **CharactersList** component. Then I'm just mapping the characters array, but that's not important. My problem is - how can I update the state using **setCharacters** function with the previous state? I know that I should do something like this:

```
setCharacters([...characters, charactersArray])
```

Can you tell me if I'm not wrong and show me in which place in my code I should do the above expression?

***Code sample***:

```
import CharactersList from 'components/CharactersList/CharactersList';
import { Button } from 'components/Button/Button';
import { GlobalStyle } from 'styles/GlobalStyle';
import { Wrapper } from './Root.styles';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { instance } from 'api/getCharacters';

const Root = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const charactersArray = [];
  const getCharacters = async () => {
    const loadedPeople = charactersArray.length;
    const maxPeople = 82;
    const perPage =
      loadedPeople === 80
        ? 2
        : loadedPeople >= maxPeople
        ? 0
        : loadedPeople < 10
        ? 10
        : 5;
    for (let index = loadedPeople; index < loadedPeople + perPage; index++) {
      const character = await instance.get(`${index + 1}`).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });
      charactersArray.push(character.data);
    }
    console.log(charactersArray);
  };
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Button onClick={getCharacters}>Fetch</Button>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <CharactersList data={characters} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, follow clean-code principles.

And **instance** is not a known keyword for the API namespace.
e.g: you can use `api().get('...')` or `ApiCharachters.list()`

> I'm not sure about your async callback function. Read some articles before using it.

And I think it could be better like this:

```
const MAX_PEOPLE = 82;

function calcPerPage(loaded) {
  if (loaded === 80) return 2;
  else if (loaded >= MAX_PEOPLE) return 0;

  return loaded < 10 ? 10 : 5;
}

const Root = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);

  const handleGetCharacters = async () => {
    const loadedPeople = characters.length;
    const perPage = calcPerPage(loadedPeople);

    for (let i = loadedPeople; i < loadedPeople + perPage; i++) {
      const character = await instance.get(`${i + 1}`).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });

      setCharacters((prev) => [...prev, character]);
    }

    console.log(characters);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Button onClick={handleGetCharacters}>Fetch</Button>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <CharactersList data={characters} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: And remember, don't call setState in a loop.

Comment: But the character variable is const, so I can't update the state outside of this loop because my variable is not available.

Comment: Maybe you can push it to an array and finally, call just one setState.

Comment: I can, but setState inside a loop is bad practice or why i shouldn't call it there?

Comment: it's a bad practice